# Heroku Rails 500 Internal Server Error - Codeship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, codeship

I've been working my way through some errors and have got to the heroku deployment, however, on the 'checking url' stage it returns a 500 error.

Here's the error logs:

```
2014-07-31T10:13:11.761170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=03eaab71-cd78-4715-801f-4fb05622a198 fwd="50.19.68.232" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=105 status=500 bytes=416 
2014-07-31T10:13:12.771487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=e9b02357-e2e4-4960-b64c-634c709c8fab fwd="23.20.32.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=10 status=500 bytes=353 
2014-07-31T10:13:13.789492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=4166b47b-d8ae-4575-9565-82d73a44e1d4 fwd="81.174.137.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=10 status=500 bytes=579 
2014-07-31T10:13:13.923179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=639e99d7-b09a-443c-9386-bdd4ed62a482 fwd="81.174.137.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=9 status=404 bytes=519 
2014-07-31T10:13:17.960963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=c2a7accf-9255-4b64-950e-d901af340ca4 fwd="23.20.32.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=10 status=500 bytes=350 
2014-07-31T10:13:23.142767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=bcd19568-5ba9-43cc-bb54-88a46be49328 fwd="23.20.32.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=9 status=500 bytes=350 
2014-07-31T10:13:28.352289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=14328198-695a-4f01-9107-b928fcf0739b fwd="23.20.32.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=19 status=500 bytes=350 
2014-07-31T10:13:33.555051+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=c9942c91-924a-4eda-828d-c1ecb7db88a0 fwd="23.20.32.241" dyno=web.1 connect=2 service=11 status=500 bytes=350 
2014-07-31T10:13:38.886327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=devonite.herokuapp.com request_id=64241c67-e519-4927-99b9-c25b4dbc0028 fwd="81.174.137.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=10 status=500 bytes=605
```

Any idea what this could be? As a total newbie to both rails and heroku I'm struggling to debug it!

Comment: Do you have a database migration locally that hasn't been run on Heroku yet?

Comment: maybe, I'm using codeship to deploy, how can I do this?

Comment: I know nothing about Codeship, sorry.  Running `heroku run rake db:migrate` from a command prompt is the normal way to migrate.  But I don't know if Codeship does that for you.  If it does, you should mention that you're using Codeship to deploy in your question's title.  Other Codeship users might be able to help.